# Angular 5 binding model using conditionnal

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular2-ngmodel

I'm using Angular 5 and i'm trying to bind a specific model according to a value that i have in the localstorage.

I tried this, i have no error but it's doesnt seem to bind to the right model :

```
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="userStorage == null ? book.autorid : book.id">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let book of bookList" [value]="book.value">
                        {{book.viewValue}}
       </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```html
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="bookValue" [value]="userStorage == null ? book.autorid : book.id">
```

Comment: Hi Fred, the value that should be the default value in the select list is not displayed and still empty

Comment: Helo @dwayne, try do this test, in down mat-select{{ userStorage }} to se whats the value, and try do this also in book, like {{ book | json }} to se the value.

Comment: i'm able to see the value of {{userStorage}} and also for the {{book.id}} But the value is not set by default in the dropdownlist

Comment: do this. <mat-select [(ngModel)]="bookValue" [value]="bookValue"> and in your component ts do the method for do this.bookValue = userStorage == null ? book.autorid : book.id; remember this value must have in your list (bookList) , bookvalue must have same value as bookValue

Comment: There's no way to do it in the Template ?  I already did it in the component.ts but i will have many mat-select in the template that i will have inside a loop. So it's better for me to do it in a template